# Remote deploy of Kivy code

Tags: android, deployment, kivy

## What am I trying to do?

I would like to be able to remotely update my Kivy code.

## What have I tried?

### os.system

From inside my Kivy code, I called `os.system('pm install -r /sdcard/my_app.apk')`. It doesn't seem to work.

### Kivy Launcher

Execution of my app from Kivy Launcher failed because my imports were not found `ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy`. Besides, my splash screen was not shown and there was no direct shortcut on the desktop to my app.

## The question

Can I use any of the methods above or any other way to deploy new versions of my kivy code? Do I have to use Google Play?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an updater for this purpose: https://github.com/kived/py4a-updater

It supports normal updates (which will show the installation dialog to the user) as well as root updates (which will just update without user input). Obviously, you need a rooted device to use root updates.

Basically, you put your APK on a web site, along with a text file which contains the version number. The updater will check the version in that text file, and if the installed version doesn't match, it will download and update. Check out the UpdaterTest app, included in the git repo, for a usage example.

Comment: Great solution :) I might add `exec downloaded_code` feature to that.

Should I run setup.py on android? Otherwise the app path and the service path does not match ('service.pyupdater' vs just 'pyupdater').

Comment: I don't actually use the setup.py, though it could be used in a recipe. I just include the `pyupdater` package in my app code (as shown in the UpdaterTest example app). It can be imported `from pyupdater ...` from either the app or the service.

Comment: Strange, when I put the pyupdater in the root, the service prints `ImportError: No module named pyupdater.service`